# Merge Overlapping intervals C++ problem solving

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, stdvector

**The question is from InterviewBit(coding website):**

> Given a collection of intervals, merge all overlapping intervals. For example:
>
> Given: [1,3],[2,6],[8,10],[15,18]
>
> return: [1,6],[8,10],[15,18].
>
> Make sure the returned intervals are sorted.

I hope my logic is correct, but I get errors in the code. Maybe because I've not used the vectors properly? My code is:

```
vector<Interval> Solution::merge(vector<Interval> &A) {
    // Do not write main() function.
    // Do not read input, instead use the arguments to the function.
    // Do not print the output, instead return values as specified
    // Still have a doubt. Checkout www.interviewbit.com/pages/sample_codes/ for more details
    vector<int> mergedIntervals;
    if(A.size()==0){
        return A;
    }
    sort(A.begin(),A.end());
    //temp vector to store first ele 
    vector<int> tempInterval=A[0];
    
    //merge operation
    for(auto it: A){
        if(it[0]<tempInterval[1]){
            tempInterval[1]=max(it[1],tempInterval[1]);
        }
        else{
            mergedIntervals.push_back(tempInterval);
            tempInterval=it;
        }
        mergedIntervals.push_back(tempInterval);
        return mergedIntervals;
    }
    
}
/**
 * Definition for an interval.
 * struct Interval {
 *     int start;
 *     int end;
 *     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
 *     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
 * };
 */
```

**Error:**

```
Compiling your Code...
> Error!
solution.cpp: In member function 'std::vector<Interval> Solution::merge(std::vector<Interval>&)':

solution.cpp:21:33: error: conversion from '__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<Interval>, Interval>::value_type' {aka 'Interval'} to non-scalar type 'std::vector<int>' requested

   25 |     vector<int> tempInterval=A[0];

      |                                 ^

solution.cpp:25:14: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Interval' and 'int')

   29 |         if(it[0]<tempInterval[1]){

      |              ^

solution.cpp:26:35: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'Interval' and 'int')

   30 |             tempInterval[1]=max(it[1],tempInterval[1]);

      |  

                             ^
```

and so on..

Comment: `Interval` is not a built-in type. Show its definition.

Comment: Take the first error `vector<int> tempInterval=A[0];` `A` is a `vector<Interval>` so `A[0]` is an `Interval`. You are trying to assign that to a different type `vector<int>` and these are not compatible. I'd like to suggest a fix, but unfortunately you haven't said what `Interval` is, please include that in the question.

Comment: @paddy i just edited it..u can see the definition in the qn now

Comment: @john I added the definition now

Comment: OK, so `vector<int> tempInterval=A[0];` could be `Interval tempInterval=A[0];`, that would at least compile.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that an interval is like a little two element vector. But as you can see from your definition it is not.

Comment: Hm... I'd accept the source vector by value (then you get a copy automatically), sort that as you did already and then merge *in place*...

Comment: And `if(it[0]<tempInterval[1]){` could be `if(it.start<tempInterval.end){` which again would compile.

Comment: You likely need to provide a custom comparator for `std::sort` (I wouldn't provide a general `operator<` for intervals as requirements might be different within different situations...).

Comment: @VishnuKc I'm not sure of the logic of your solution, I'm just suggesting ways to make the code compile.

Comment: @john i tried what u said..and got this error...error: base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Interval'

   29 |        if(it->start<tempInterval.end){

      |             ^~

Comment: And (I'm sure about this one) `vector<int> mergedIntervals;` should be `vector<Interval> mergedIntervals;`

Comment: @VishnuKc Yes, sorry that was my mistake, I meant `.` not `->`

Comment: @john yea I figured that out..now im gettin this "error: 'struct Interval' has no member named 'push_back' " . We can't use push_back for vectors or wat?

Comment: @VishnuKc Yes you can use push_back for vectors, but as the error says you have an Interval not a vector. You'll have to show the line of code that causes this error, and how the variables in it are declared.

Comment: Looks like you copied your answer from leetcode (which uses vector<int>) to InterviewBit (which uses Interval).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Uh... isn't that be cheating? Shouldn't we then rather stop providing any further support for that at all???

Comment: @Aconcagua debatable

Answer (score 0):

You can do quite a bit better:

At first, accept the vector *by value* – this creates a copy right on the start:

```
vector<Interval> Solution::merge(vector<Interval> data)
// (note the dropped ampersand!)
```

Then you can merge the intervals within this copy *in place*! For the case that you should not be *allowed* to or otherwise be prevented from that modification (no access to the header used for the tests) then you can (and only then you should) simply create a *copy* of the argument and continue with that one:

```
vector<Interval> Solution::merge(vector<Interval>& source)
{
    std::vector data(source); // just create a copy as very first step
                              // and continue operating on this...
    // ...
```

You still need to sort, but I assume you didn't provide a custom `operator<` for the `Interval` class anyway (and I would't do so either because requirements might change pretty much depending on the specific use case), so you might provide the appropriate comparator explicitly:

```
std::sort
(
    data.begin(), data.end(),
    [](Interval const& x, Interval const& y)
    {
        return x.begin < y.begin;
    }
);
```

Finally you can now merge, as mentioned, in place, by only retaining the merged elements (similar as `std::remove`/`std::remove_if` do):

```
auto cur = data.begin();
for(auto i = cur; i != data.end(); ++i)  // you could start with cur + 1, too, but
                                         // that would require special handling
                                         // for the empty vector... 
{
    if(i->begin <= cur->end)
    {
        // intervals overlap (or touch) -> need to merge!
        cur->end = std::max(cur->end, i->end); // enlarges the interval, if need be
    }
    else
    {
        // no overlap any more, need to start a new interval
        // -> copy current towards front (note: there might be a gap
        //    due to already merged intervals!)
        *++cur = std::move(*i);
        // (moving is always correct, but not necessary HERE as identical to
        // copying anyway – I recommend still adding it by principle to get
        // used to when re-using the pattern elsewhere)
    }
}
```

Now cur points to the last element to be retained, we need yet to remove
// the surplus ones (this is called the [erase-remove-idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom)):

```
data.erase(++cur, data.end()); // note: need to increment to point BEHIND
                               // the last element to be retained!
```

All you yet need to do is return the vector received that way ;)

Final notes:

- This is entirely *untested* code – if you find a bug, please fix yourself.
- This code assumes the intervals already being normalised (as your original version does as well) – if you cannot expect this as pre-condition you might want to add code to fix (swapping `begin` and `end` members if the latter smaller than the former).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Well, OK, I added a few lines for that case, indeed, there might be no access to the headers on the test system... Apart from there's no compatibility issue in *this* case (assuming no in-place-merge expected), so this discussion doesn't appear of further value to me (dropped my comments already).

Answer (score 0):

When I change `vector<int>` to `Interval` I get this:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std; // this is bad but all the stupid sites open std

struct Interval {
     int start;
     int end;
     Interval() : start(0), end(0) {}
     Interval(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e) {}
};

vector<Interval> merge(vector<Interval> &A) {
    // Do not write main() function.
    // Do not read input, instead use the arguments to the function.
    // Do not print the output, instead return values as specified
    // Still have a doubt. Checkout www.interviewbit.com/pages/sample_codes/ for more details
    vector<Interval> mergedIntervals;
    if (A.size()==0){
        return A;
    }
    sort(A.begin(), A.end(),
         [](const Interval &lhs, const Interval &rhs) {
            return lhs.start < rhs.start;
        });
    //temp vector to store first ele 
    Interval tempInterval=A[0];
    
    //merge operation
    for (const auto &it: A){
        if (it.start<tempInterval.end) {
            tempInterval.end=max(it.end,tempInterval.end);
        } else {
            mergedIntervals.push_back(tempInterval);
            tempInterval=it;
        }
        mergedIntervals.push_back(tempInterval);
    }
    return mergedIntervals;    
}
```

The only tricky bit is that Interval lacks `operator<` so you have to provide a comparison for `sort`.

You can improve that by reserving space in `mergedIntervals` or even better do it in-place in `A` and trim `A` to fit.

And obviously you should never ever ever ever ever ever ever write a function signature like that. Use:

```
vector<Interval> merge(const vector<Interval> &A);
vector<Interval> merge(vector<Interval> &&A);
void merge_in_place(vector<Interval> &A);
```

Comment: The last `mergedIntervals.push_back(tempInterval);` should be moved right before the `return`, outside the loop.